# Trading system via php and sql

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to create a function to a website that can make users to be able to send "coins" to each other and I have some issues with SQL.

At first I tried to use `INSERT` to the addressee and use `UPDATE` to the sender but it didn't succeed.

So the question is, how can I make the system to

1. Make the specific user get the package
2. Subtract the "coins" from the sender

at the same time.

p.s I'm using xampp

If someone can help or redirect me to a guide it will be great.
Thanks

Comment: Hello @xQwerty, posting the actual code you need help with is what SO is mainly about. More here: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: actully after i failed couple of time i decided to delete all the code and to start a new one from nothing. i kept only the html code which i have no problem with

Answer (score 0):

You could create a separate table called "transaction", it contains, among others, the fields "sender", "receiver" and "amount". That way you only have to INSERT one row to do the sending and receiving simultaneous. The amount of coins you have can be computed by seeing how many coins you've send and received.

Another method would be to use [transactions](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-transaction.aspx). That way you can make multiple queries act as one.

Both are valid methods, and there are probably other solutions as well.